# Matlplotlib plot with inset: make legend in original axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, axes

I have a very simple question that I can't find the answer to:

Using matplotlib I plot something in a main plot and then something else in an inset using e.g.

```
a = plt.axes([.2, .64, .28, .24])
```

But after that I want to plot a legend in the main plot again (because the legend contains something found in the meantime).

How do I do this? As in how do I go back to the original plot and make the legend?

I tried different things including `sca`, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.sca(main_ax)` should have worked.  Note that if you didn't specify a label for the curve/plot/etc, it won't be shown if you only call `plt.legend()`.  (Instead, you'd need to do `plt.legend([line], [label])`, or better yet, call `plot(x, y, label='some label')`.)

However, it's better to approach the problem a different way.

This is one of the many reasons why you'll often see people recommend avoiding the `pyplot` interface and using Axes/Figure methods instead.  It makes it very clear which axes you're operating on.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10), label='Curve 1')

inset = fig.add_axes([.2, .64, .28, .24])
inset.scatter(range(3), range(3))

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]